# using jquery show and hide content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### html

```
<ul class="services_menu">
    <li>
        <div class="servic">
            <a class="servic_icon" onclick="dispServices(this)"><i class="ux1"></i><span class="tx">UX</span></a>
            <ul class="toggleSubService">
                <li>Wireframing</li>
                <li>Content Strategy</li>
                <li>Information Architecture</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="servic">
            <a class="servic_icon" onclick="dispServices(this)"><i class="ux2"></i><span class="tx">DESIGN</span></a>
            <ul class="toggleSubService">
                <li>Branding</li>
                <li>Web Design</li>
                <li>Web Design</li>
                <li>Web Design</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
.toggleSubService{ display:none; }
```

### js

```
function dispServices(e) {
    e = $(e);
    e.parent().find('ul.toggleSubService').fadeToggle(300);
}
```

### problem:

onclick a tag having .servic_icon class I want to show and hide ul.toggleSubService, and if clicked on body or outside ul.toggleSubService the ul.toggleSubService needs to hide. 
I don't know how to trigger my click event.

If I am clicking on a.servic_icon and again clicking on another a.servic_icon  the previous one is not hiding.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery

```
$('.servic_icon').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div.servic').find('ul').toggle();
});
```

And fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvC8B/)

Answer (score 0):

> function validateSubmit2(id){     if(id){         $("#"+id).hide(
>
> ```
>       }
> ```